# Unable to create new React app -- fatal: unable to look up github.scm.corp.ebay.com (port 9418) (No such host is known.)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using Windows 10 and Powershell to install new React app. I have Node v12.13.0 installed as well.

The information in the log where the error occured states:

```
> 323 verbose npm  v6.12.0 324 error Error while executing: 324 error
> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t
> git://github.scm.corp.ebay.com/cubejs-ebay/ebay-global-header-node.git
> 324 error 324 error fatal: unable to look up github.scm.corp.ebay.com
> (port 9418) (No such host is known. ) 324 error 324 error exited with
> error code: 128 325 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

It seems like a fairly basic issue but I was unable to find much through searching. Anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: how are you trying to install the react app?

Comment: I used `npm install -g create-react-app` and then `npm install create-react-app my-app`

Comment: your second command is wrong. it will try to install `my-app` which is probably giving you that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe your syntax when call `create-react-app` is incorrect.

Try `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: Awesome, worked! Can you explain why I needed to use `npx` instead?

Comment: you don't need `npx`, that's just a shortcut for `npm i -g create-react-app && create-react-app my-app && npm u -g create-react-app`

Comment: `npx` is npm package executor, so it allow you to run npm package without install it before. Like @azium commented above :smile: